# Docker - ssh by container name

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, docker-compose

I want to easy ssh to docker container by container name.
Now to ssh to container i need to call:

```
docker ps
```

which returns:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE
<container_id>        myContainer
```

and copy CONTAINER_ID to execute command:

```
docker exec -ti <container_id> /bin/bash/
```

I have many containers and it will be much easier to ssh by IMAGE name.
Is it possible without writting custom bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, as long as you don't install the SSH client inside every container no, it is not possible to "ssh" inside a container.

Please note that you can use `container name` instead of `container id` to exec a command (/bin/bash in your case) into a running container.

For example, given a container like this:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
5b3068b4e51c        registry_registry                       "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   4 months ago        Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp             registry_registry_1
```

Running the following 2 command leads to the same result:

```
docker exec -ti 5b3068b4e51c /bin/bash
docker exec -ti registry_registry_1 /bin/bash
```

Furthermore, again in general, you could have more that one container running for the same image, thus what you want to achive (enter a container by image name) isn't much safe.